# Jquery selector seems not to work in google chrome

Tags: jquery-selectors, drupal-7

I want to update the value from a input/textfield with a calculated value from the cookie.It's like a mini local cookie cart.
Saving and retrieving the json from the cookie is a piece of cake.
In my behavior I fail to make the following work:

I added a class for every node in the input field, it's constructed like the example below.

```
Myid = 'webform_cart_nid_10';
formElement = $('.' + Myid);
console.log(formElement);
```

The html is quite nested and can be seen http://it2servu.be/broodjes/bestellen (if I may link?) .
the field whose value I want to update looks like this:

```
<input class="webform_cart_nid_10 webform_cart_nid form-text" type="text" id="edit-submitted-cart-item-cart-elements-10" name="submitted[cart_item][cart_elements][10]" value="0" size="3" maxlength="128">
```

Is contained in drupal output with severe div-itis.

```
    <div class="page clearfix" id="page">
     <div id="section-content" class="section section-content">
      <div id="zone-content-wrapper" class="zone-wrapper zone-content-wrapper clearfix">  
       <div id="zone-content" class="zone zone-content clearfix container-12">    
        <div class="grid-12 region region-content" id="region-content">
         <div class="region-inner region-content-inner">
          <div class="block-inner clearfix">
           <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="node node-webform node-promoted view-mode-full clearfix ">
             <div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
               <form class="webform-client-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/broodjes/bestellen" method="post" id="webform-client-form-5" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <div>
                 <fieldset class="collapsible form-wrapper collapse-processed" id="edit-submitted-cart-item-cart-elements">
                  <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
                   <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-submitted-cart-item-cart-elements-10">
                    <input class="webform_cart_nid_10 webform_cart_nid form-text" type="text" id="edit-submitted-cart-item-cart-elements-10" name="submitted[cart_item][cart_elements][10]" value="0" size="3" maxlength="128">
...
```

probably it's something stupid, I just can't figure out what it is?

Comment: Your `Myid` variable holds the class **?!** Anyway `$` is `undifined` in your site, use `jQuery` instead.

Comment: That was just for debugging of the problem, not permanent ofcourse.
I have rewritten the script. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with jQuery. If you pop open the console in Chrome and type jQuery, it returns the jQuery function. If you type $ it returns undefined. You have some sort of collision causing $ not to be set to jQuery.

Comment: Exactly what I thought.How do I debug this? Can I just log the function throughout my code and see where it goes wrong? I'll try that later today! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

use "jQuery" instead of "$"

```
Myid = 'webform_cart_nid_10';
formElement = jQuery('.' + Myid);
console.log(formElement);
```

the "$" never worked for me in Drupal 7.